# Why does God permit wickedness?

Tags: job, jeremiah, habakkuk

You may have asked yourself this question or your friends or perhaps your preacher. Do not be amazed, the question is not new, faithful servants of God have asked the same question.

Job asked.

> Job 21:7  (NASB)  “Why do the wicked still live, Continue on, also
> become very powerful?

Evil must have been rampant  among his countrymen during his times, trouble by this Jeremiah  asked:

Jeremiah 12:1 (NASB)

> 12 Righteous are You, O Lord, that I would plead my case with You;
> Indeed I would discuss matters of justice with You:  Why has the way
> of the wicked prospered? Why are all those who deal in treachery at
> ease?

Habakkuk in his prayer to God asked: "Why do you force me to see oppression? God did not belittle his prophet but reassured him.

Habakkuk 1:3 NET

> Why do you force me to witness injustice?  Why do you put up with
> wrongdoing?[c]Destruction and violence confront me; conflict is
> present and one must endure strife.

**The question is: Why does God allow oppression?**

**Dear Voters to close,** What would you say, If someone were to ask you: "What is the main theme of the Bible?"Why rush to close a question that the prophets of God asked their creator, he did not scoff at them but gradually revealed the answer to us by means of them and his Son. Read Isaiah 11:11:1-10

**The Scriptures give assurance that the time will come when wickedness will no longer exist, as all those who stand in opposition to the Creator will be destroyed when his permission of wickedness will have served its purpose.​—2Pe 3:9-13; Re 18:20-24; 19:11–20:3, 7-10.**

I urge you to reconsider your decision Tks.

Comment: God is free (which is why He's called Lord, and not slave), and made man in His own image, as ruler (Genesis 1:26-28). Secondly, his inner well-being is independent of externals; as such, so is man's, since, as already stated, the latter was made in His image; hence no actual "need" to "do" anything (about anything); rather, if man wants to enter His state of mind, no one is stopping him (Psalm 34:8). Thirdly, His state of mind is the product of His own character or way of being, of which honesty and sincerity form an integral part, adversity and uncertainty providing for the latter.

Comment: The answer is discovered by asking why God placed the deceiver in the garden to begin with. He didn't merely permit it, He mandated it to be part of our experience.

Comment: God did not "place the deceiver in the Garden" anymore than God mandated that Adam sin. Such a conclusion of God's intention is unsupported Biblically.

Comment: Oh, so why was he there? Everything God does has a purpose - clearly evil too has a purpose - for a time at least.

Comment: @user48152 - Satan was there for the same reason that Adam sinned - He decided to do it.  That is, unless you want to accused God of forcing Adam to sin and removing his choice?

Comment: This looks like a theological/theodicy question, not an exegetical question about Habakkuk.

Comment: I agree with @curiousdannii This is a personal matter (regarding Deity) and not a matter of the hermeneutical analysis of the word of God.

Comment: Why is this being voted to be closed? Just because one doesn’t have an answer or can’t imagine an non theological answer doesn’t mean it’s not possible to derive an answer from the text and the Bible. I was so looking forward to answering once I had some free time.

Comment: Nihil Sine Deo :Tks The answer is in the scriptures and it is the main theme of the Bible.  Read also my comments to Dottard .Thks again

Comment: Nigel J and curiousdannii :The Scriptures give assurance that the time will come when wickedness will no longer exist, as all those who stand in opposition to the Creator will be destroyed when his permission of wickedness will have served its purpose.​2 Peter 3:9-13; Rev. 18:20-24; 19:11–20:3, 7-10.

Comment: This is a good question, but I feel like it would work better on Christianity SE because it's about systematics rather than a specific text.

Answer (score 2):

Light is an actual thing and it has a source while darkness is no thing at all but just an absence of light.  If I cover a lit candle in a shoe box, turn off the lights in the room, and uncover the box, light permeates the darkness.  If I cover an empty shoe box in a dark room, turn on the lights, and uncover the box (releasing the darkness), no dimming of the light occurs.

In the same way evil is the absence of good, and is no actual thing at all:  It's only source is the depth of it's lack.  Since only God is good, evil is a rejection of God.

The question ultimately asks, "Why does God allow people to reject Him?"

A loaded gun to the head and a demand of "Love me!" would not produce free love from the heart:  there is only fear here.  What we have in Scripture is not a threat of "love me or else".  What we do have is a clear presentation that loving God is the only access to the source of good and light and a declaration of the consequences/lack associated with rejection.

True power, sovereignty, and love does not bind a heart in chains but it pleads, and acts, and mourns.  Every good Father has lived this.

> “O Jerusalem, Jerusalem, the city that kills the prophets and stones those who are sent to it! How often would I have gathered your children together as a hen gathers her brood under her wings, **and you were not willing**! - Matthew 23:37

Comment: interesting - tho in yr example, your darkness has no power (or source), whereas your light does. In the real 'world' evil does too. So it IS real and until it's power/source is removed it will exist and have influence. It had influence over Jesus and his life was one of constant resistance. Heb 2:14 ...He might render powerless... 2 Tim1:10 He broke the power of death and illuminated the way to life

Comment: God created darkness therefore your definition of darkness is flawed Biblically speaking

Comment: @user48152 Evil does have a 'source'...rejection of God and power according to the depth of that rejection.  The sting of death is sin and the power of sin is the Law.

Comment: @NihilSineDeo Did He?  I am aware that He created light, separated them from each other, and named them.

Comment: @NihilSineDeo Isaiah 45:7 (YLT) 'Forming light, and preparing darkness, Making peace, and preparing evil, I am Jehovah, doing all these things.'  If create replaces prepare (as many translations have) then, if God has directly created darkness, He has directly created evil also.

Comment: You use YLT but the Hebrew doesn’t help your cause and the LXX Greek doesn’t either. Hence why your explanation/conclusion  is flawed

Comment: @NihilSineDeo Did God create evil, then?  Isaiah 45:7 has the same word (בּרא) in both places.

Comment: I never said He didn’t ... what’s your point? I said that darkness was created... like bad/evil was also created. Did God not create hell for the fallen angels? Of course He did. Is hell not evil? But it’s also just.

Comment: @NihilSineDeo Hell=evil and hell=just, therefore evil=just.  I can't go there with you.  Hell is the consequence of evil.  Outer darkness.  Rejection of light.  I understand your position to be that God created darkness and then spoke light into it but the Isaiah verse has it in the opposite order and so must be dealing with moral darkness and light rather than physical.

Comment: I didn’t say evil is just.

Answer (score 1):

I note the following:

- 1 John 4:7, 8 - Beloved, let us love one another, because love comes from God. Everyone who loves has been born of God and knows God. Whoever does not love does not know God, because **God is love**.
- 1 John 4:16, 17 - And we have come to know and believe the love that God has for us. **God is love**; whoever abides in love abides in God, and God in him. In this way, love has been perfected among us ...
- John 13:34, 35 - "A new commandment I give you: Love one another. As I have loved you, so you also must love one another. By this everyone will know that you are My disciples, if you love one another.”
- Deut 6:5 - you shall love the LORD your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your strength.
- Lev 19:18 - Do not seek revenge or bear a grudge against any of your people, but love your neighbor as yourself. I am the LORD.
- 2 Cor 5:14 - For Christ’s love compels us, because we are convinced that One died for all, therefore all died.
- Eph 2:4, 5 - But because of His great love for us, God, who is rich in mercy, made us alive with Christ even when we were dead in our trespasses. It is by grace you have been saved!

... and so forth.  Love is at the very basis of God's nature; the essential characteristic of His being, the primary component of His character; and we are told to be the same.

Now, here is the nub of the matter: Love that is compelled is not love at all.  That is, forced love is a contradiction in terms.  By definition, love must be free or it ceases to be love.

If God prevented all wickedness, then He would remove all freedom of choice and there could not be love.

So, why does God allow evil (Psalm 73)?  God allows evil because God is love and, as such, there must be freedom, else there cannot be love.

This is not to suggest that things will always be this way - God will resolve matters and ultimately destroy the wicked (Rev 20) but in such a way that does not violate His principled love for all.  (Compare the request of the wicked in Rev 6:15-17 to be destroyed!)

Comment: Dottard The rebellion initiated by Satan called into question the rightfulness and righteousness of God’s sovereignty, that is, whether God’s rulership over his creatures is exercised righteously and in their best interests. The fact that Adam and Eve rebelled also raised another issue: Would all other intelligent creatures prove unfaithful and disloyal to God when obedience appeared to bring no material benefits? Satan’s claim respecting faithful Job implied that they would do so. Satan said: Read Job 2:4-5

Comment: @OzzieOzzie - I agree - no dispute with that.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, it is for God's glory.

> John 9:1 As he [Jesus] went along, he saw a man blind from birth. 2His disciples asked him, “Rabbi, who sinned, this man or his parents, that he was born blind?”
> 3“Neither this man nor his parents sinned,” said Jesus, “but this happened so that the **works of God might be displayed in him**.

> Revelation 6:11
> Then each of them was given a white robe, and they were told to wait a little longer, until the **full number** of their fellow servants, their brothers and sisters, were killed just as they had been.

God permits wickedness in the world to test the hearts of man, good or bad, so that the works of the godly might be displayed. Ultimately, it leads to the Cross and the glory of the Cross.

Comment: At God's declared time he will glorify his name by doing away with wickedness:  " And I will execute great vengeance upon them with wrathful rebukes; and they shall know that I am Jehovah, when I shall lay my vengeance upon them." and " And I will magnify myself, and sanctify myself, and I will make myself known in the eyes of many nations; and they shall know that I am Jehovah.Ezekiel 25:17 and 38:23 ASV Tks

Comment: Great. I also agree with you that questions are being closed too quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Why does God allow oppression? May be re-posed in several ways...

Why does **God** allow oppression?

**Why** does God allow oppression?

Why does God allow **oppression**?

I'll ignore the 4th option as it is a flawed concept to some degree.

The core of these Q's depends on where oppression comes from. It is not of God, so it must come from that which is not God, aka evil - the god of this world.

Therefore, oppression comes from evil, evil is not of God; so where does evil come from and what is it's purpose?

God designed His recreation with mankind with attention to detail that blows our minds!
From the nano to the cosmic wonder, God has placed everything in harmony. Even though there is much corruption, harmony persists in most of creation.

Harmony is perhaps most lacking in the heart and mind of man where the devil has been hardest at work.

> “The human heart is the most deceitful of all things, and desperately
> wicked. Who really knows how bad it is? Jer 17:9

This adversary, devil, Satan, whatever we call him, is also part of God's plan for man - as were the two trees, 'in the midst of the garden' Gen 2:9

One led to death, one to life.

The adversary was also there because God had decided that, with His wise oversight and foreknowing, great good will come as a result.

Do you think for a moment that God couldn't banish him to a distant galaxy - or perhaps another dimension?
No, God inserted evil into the very beginning of mankind on purpose - knowing the pain, the death, the suffering that would ensue.
The serpent, there to cause havoc, was only able to function within the environment God created - centred on the two trees!
The choice that was made was skewed away from God because of the lies that clouded the humans judgement. There was a 'social influencer' in the garden!

As usual in such matters, truth is the first casualty.

A massive, cosmic altering choice, that was made in deception - that God provided the means for. Was this path inevitable?

> Simply put, God COULD have made a new beginning with mankind, only
> provided them with His loving company and guidance and with no sense
> or presence of evil to affect their existence, life might have gone on
> merrily - but He didn't!

If God had chosen the 'pure only' path, perhaps, the new man may have followed the course of Satan anyway as described in,

> Ezekiel 28:11-15 You were blameless in your ways
> From the day you were created
> Until unrighteousness was found in you

Oppression is but one of many elements of evil, that find life in us through sin - choosing other than God and His appointed way that leads to happiness etc. For there to be oppression - there must be an oppressor - this is ultimately the devil who exerts influence over the world until his time is up.

Thankfully, it is already a foregone conclusion - Jesus won the biggest battle of the cosmos on fair and just terms. As a second Adam/human, he defeated evil for us all. (with his Father and God's constant assistance to the very last breath)

For more on this why evil exists, see other answer here.
[Does God ordain evil?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/49366/does-god-ordain-evil/49367#49367)