# Why is Jeremiah 31 addressed to Ephraim?

Tags: jeremiah

Jeremiah 31 is one of my favorite in Tanach. In very poetic language, the chapter describes God's love for his people and the future redemption of the Israelite nation. I wrote a bit about this chapter in an answer to a different question [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/203/76).

The subject of this chapter is unambigiously "Ephraim," one of the twelve tribes of Israel:

> There will be a day when watchmen cry out
>       on the **hills of Ephraim**, ‘Come, let us go up to Zion,
>       to the Lord our God.’” (31:6 [NIV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Jeremiah%2031&version=NIV))
>
> See, I will bring them from the land of the north
>       and gather them from the ends of the earth. ...I will lead them beside streams of water
>       on a level path where they will not stumble, because I am Israel’s father,
>       and **Ephraim is my firstborn son**. (8-9)
>
> I have surely heard **Ephraim’s** moaning:
>       ‘You disciplined me like an unruly calf,
>       and I have been disciplined. Restore me, and I will return,
>       because you are the Lord my God. (18)
>
> “A voice is heard in Ramah [should be translated: a voice is heard *on high*],
>       mourning and great weeping, Rachel weeping for her children
>       and refusing to be comforted,
>       because they are no more.” (15)

Rachel, one of Jacob's wives, is the grandmother of Ephraim.

In general, Ephraim is used as a synecdoche to refer to the whole Northern Kingdom of Israel. The tribe of Ephraim inhabited the northern part of Israel. Jeroboam, the first king of the Northern Kingdom was from the tribe of Ephraim and the later prophets often refer to the Northern Kingdom by the name Ephraim (eg: most of the prophecies in Hoshea are addressed to Ephraim).

Jeremiah functions as a prophet until after the destruction of the Southern Kingdom around the year 586 BCE which means he was born well after the northern kingdom of Israel was destroyed and exiled in the year 722 BCE (136 years earlier). So why is Jeremiah suddenly addressing himself to Ephraim? What is the signficance of this chapter? Is there an implicit message that the Southern Kingdom is supposed to take from this?

Comment: Could it be that Ephraim ( A great company of nations...The USA ) will soon loose her "fatness and become lean"? And during her mourning will return to the land of her youth?

Comment: @Todd I don't think it needs to be any political nation. I think the children of Israel (10 tribes) were scattered over the whole world. So that would include a lot of Americans, but many many others as well. Consider the end of Jer 31, that the offspring of Israel will not pass away or be lost any sooner than the sun, moon and stars move from their order or the universe is explored.

Comment: Related: "[What is the name of Joseph's Tribe](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/8045/)"

Answer (score 6):

Ephraim is Jacob's eldest son by 'adoption', replacing Reuben [who he rejects](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2049:3-4&version=ESV):

> <sup>5</sup>And now your two sons, who were born to you in the land of Egypt before I came to you in Egypt, are mine; Ephraim and Manasseh shall be mine, as Reuben and Simeon are. <sub>[ESV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+48:5&version=ESV)</sub>

According to Jacob's blessing he hopes for Ephraim to carry on his name (despite [Joseph's protestations](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2048:18&version=ESV) that it should be his firstborn, Manassah who has the role):

> <sup>15</sup>And he blessed Joseph and said, “The God before whom my fathers Abraham and Isaac walked, the God who has been my shepherd all my life long to this day, <sup>16</sup>the angel who has redeemed me from all evil, bless the boys; and in them ***let my name be carried on***, and the name of my fathers Abraham and Isaac; and let them grow into a multitude in the midst of the earth.” <sub>[ESV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2048:15-16&version=ESV)</sub>

You mention that 'Ephraim' becomes a name for [the entire Northern Kingdom](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah+7:9&version=ESV), which is also true of the name 'Israel' (though unlike 'Ephraim', the latter is later used to refer to Judah after the northern Kingdom is destroyed).

> *Why is Jeremiah 31 addressed to Ephraim?*

I don't think it is 'addressed' to Ephraim, rather it is about the fulfilment of God's promises to Abraham - Jeremiah is looking forward to the future 'day' when God will gather together the remnant of his people who have been disciplined by him and scattered.

Now judgement [has fallen on Judah](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Jeremiah+29&version=ESV) as well (though there is more to come), it is no longer an option for them to believe that they are the 'true' Israel and that all the other tribes have been rejected - for God to gather a people for himself, He *must* do it from among the people he has judged - hence the constant question/tension from Genesis 12 onwards, "Who will inherit the promises to Abraham" takes another twist and a word from God is given through Jeremiah ([among](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah+10:20&version=ESV) [others](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Micah%205:3&version=ESV)):

> <sup>2</sup>“Thus says the Lord, the God of Israel: Write in a book all the words that I have spoken to you. <sup>3</sup>For behold, days are coming, declares the Lord, when ***I will restore the fortunes of my people, Israel and Judah***, says the Lord, and I will ***bring them back to the land that I gave to their fathers***, and they shall take possession of it.” <sub>[ESV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Jeremiah%2030:2-3&version=ESV)</sub>

Comment: Bit late, but I'm curious about your statement that the term "Israel" is used to refer to Judah after the norther kingdom is scattered. There are many places where house of Judah and house of Israel are separated in the same verse. Jer 31:27,31 says "house of Judah/Israel" and then v33 says ONLY "house of Israel". So, regarding the question, Jer 31:2-22 mentions only things specific to Ephraim: their famous vineyards, mountains of Samaria, a voice in Ramah (in north) and repeated mentions of Ephraim. Why would Jeremiah, during Judah's exile, identify them by the name of their enemy, Israel?

Answer (score 0):

Ephraim was the strongest tribe to the west of the tabernacle prior to the Israelites entering into the promise land.  There were only two that had the courage to lead the Israelites into God's promised land after the 40 years.  One being Joshua, Moses' succeeder.  Joshua was from the tribe of Ephraim.  Once God's people finally entered into the promise land the tribe of Ephraim held in its boundaries the capital city of Shiloh.  Shiloh is also where the Ark of the Covenant was placed.  Most of the prophets address the northern kingdom as Ephraim because of this.  I gathered most of my information through studying Tabernacle, Joshua, and the  scriptures supporting Ephraim as the first land that was designated to the tribe of Ephraim, which supported the first capital city (Shiloh), which held the first true temple to house The Ark in the promise land.  If you have ever done a study on the Ark of the Covenant then you know that this was the only way to be in God's presence.  Hence the tearing of the veil when Jesus Christ died for our sins. It is my belief in JER 31:9 God says "because I am Israel's Father and Ephraim's my firstborn son", He is speaking of his firstborn temple in His people promised land. I am not a scholar though. Just a child of God seeking after his heart.  I pray this helps!

Oh and on Ephraim, Jacob's adopted son topic.  Ephraim was actually his grandson.  Ephraim was Joseph's second born but was favored by not only Joseph but by his Grandpa Jacob too.  When asked for his blessings Grandpa Jacob gave his blessings to Ephraim not the firstborn, Mannaseih, during the short time Jacob got to spend with them in Egypt.

Comment: Jeremiah chapter 31 was written some 150 years after the destruction of the Kingdom of Israel, which included Ephraim, and the exile of many Israelites. Please explain why this chapter mentions Ephraim and in what context.

Comment: @shannonjohnson Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange! [This site is a little different from other sites.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423) Be sure to visit the [tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about this site.

Answer (score 0):

Because contrary to popular opinion, many inhabitants of the northern Kingdom of Israel (AKA Ephraim) actually survived the Assyrian invasion and assimilated into the southern kingdom of Judah (1 Chronicles 9:3, 2 Chronicles 30:1-18).

One can subsequently infer that they were deported along with their Judahite brothers and later returned, thus validating Jeremiah 31.